# Multiple URL rewrite rules and get every prams

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, page-template, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I am creating a messaging system where I have 4 sections (1)inbox (2)sent (3)draft (4)unread so I decide to go with WordPress add rewrite rules

I have already added one rewrite rule section.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'messages/([^/]*)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=messages&section=$matches[1]',
'top' );
```

Now I want to add one more param after the section is the ID(inbox messages id).

so for that, I add a second rewrite rule id.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'messages/inbox/([^/]*)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=messages&id=$matches[1]&section=$matches[2]',
'top' );
```

if I visit https://example.com/messages/inbox I can get in query_vars

```
[section] => inbox
```

but the issue is that if I visit https://example.com/messages/inbox/123 I can get in query_vars

```
[section] => 
[id] => 123
```

I am not getting section value, in this case, I want to check in this URL which section Is currently that's why I need section value on this page.

Comment: `$matches[2]` in your second rewrite rule doesn't match any pattern, so you should just use `&section=inbox` there.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, thank you. Your solution is working. but I doubt that this way is right or not can you suggest a better way to achieve what I describe. or it's possible to get all params in last id page I mean can I get section dynamically in id page so I can check which section is currently in id page cause it's possible section are "inbox/id" or "sent/id" or "draft/id" and "unread/id".

Comment: In that case, you can use something like `messages/(inbox|sent|draft|unread)/(\d+)/?$` with `&section=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank You. it's worked as I want.

Answer (score 0):

See this is sort of solved in the comments and old but to save someone going down the wrong path here, I believe this is done the wrong way for OP to achieve what they want.

One re-write rule should be enough here, and then use the matches to construct your query.

Firstly, we need a Regex that will match the whole string of what you're trying to parse

Something like this will work `"/^messages\/(inbox|sent|draft|unread)\/?(\d*)?$/"`
https://regex101.com/r/33F9Po/1

That starts with `messages/` has any of `(inbox|sent|draft|unread)` in the middle, an optional slash and a second optional match group of numbers at the end.

This will allow your rewrite rule to work as follows using your `$matches`

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^messages\/(inbox|sent|draft|unread)\/?(\d*)?$',
    "index.php?pagename=messages&section=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]",
    'top'
);
```

See this page in the codex for more information and examples
[add_rewrite_rule() | Function | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)